# Xamarin binding successfull, but while using the dll in a test app, is crashing on the launch time with dyld error

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

Filtered syslog:
None found

**Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/RichRelevanceSDK.framework/RichRelevanceSDK
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B4C7D0D-F3B9-404D-A27E-1023D3468B7B/RRTestApp.app/RRTestApp
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 370.6**

Binary Images:
0xe6000 - 0x5a9fff RRTestApp armv7   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B4C7D0D-F3B9-404D-A27E-1023D3468B7B/RRTestApp.app/RRTestApp
0x1feef000 - 0x1ff16fff dyld armv7s   /usr/lib/dyld

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: ^^^ any solution or update to this question? i have a similar issue and the other posts here and on Xamarin forum arent helpful.